# Keep track of history outside of Backbone Router

Tags: backbone.js, pagination, browser-history

Is there a way to keep track of history outside of a backbone router. I have a pagination service provided by Laravel, the links between pages are like the following "#leads?page=7". Everything works, but I have no clue right now on how to apply track of history outside of the router. The router works for the dashboard options but not for the pagination.

Comment: Is it a SPA app? Why not process all url using backbone router?

Comment: Yes it is, because I'm handling the click event inside a view.

Comment: @user2814599 I have a router set and I've tried handling the pagination in it and of course it worked. But since the view that contains the paginated results it's called from the router I wanted to render theme using events.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Backbone.Marionette for a single page app, but more for varius tools on my site. I wanted to have Laravel render the initial pages for SEO reasons. I had Laravel write the first pagination block then I have Marionette rewrite it after any interaction. You have to love twice the amount of work, but I like the fact that I don't have to worry about search engine not seeing the page.

In order to do this, I ended up not using the backbone router for this tool at all. I used javascript [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). It is only available in [newish browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=history), but that is what our site supports. If you do need to support older browsers there is a [shim](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js), but I have not used it.

```
// add to history
history.pushState('', 'Search: ' + tags, url);

// get current history
updateUrl: function(){
    var currentState = history.state;
    return (currentState) ? currentState : $(this)[0].baseURI;
}
```

It definitely was more work, but I was able to get it working the way I wanted.

Comment: I ended up putting everything in the router :/

Comment: Yeah, it is. I was trying to keep the router a little more lean, but couldn't make it happen.